# form validation with jQuery - div class "required"

Tags: jquery, validation

The div class "required" must be validated. How can i do that?

```
<div id="test" class="required">
    <span class="customTextField">      
        <label for="attrValue">name</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="test" id=""/>     
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Checked like the tablecloth in an Italian restaurant? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Please give us an example of what exactly you're trying to accomplish. What have you tried so far and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#test').attr('class') == 'required'){
//validate sub input items
}
```

I understand something like above.

Answer (score 0):

Select those `input` elements that are children of the `div.required` selector and check the value length:

```
$("div.required input").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.val().length === 0) {
      //field is empty; show error
   }
});
```